# Código jQuery para TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Estou passando um código que eu havia feito em jQuery para TypeScript, e estou tendo um problema com essa função, por causa do `.filter()`, que na verdade, pelo que eu entendi, não existe no TypeScript, apenas em arrays.

Peço a ajuda de vocês para transformar esta função para TypeScript.

Obrigado.
Em TypeScript:

```
document.getElementById("enter").addEventListener("click", function () {
        (document.getElementById("form-login").querySelectorAll("[required]"), this.closest("form")).filter(function (i, e) {
            return !e.val().trim();
        }).val('');

        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("numeroSerie")).value = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("numeroSerie")).value.trim();
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("user")).value = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("user")).value.trim();
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("pass")).value = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("pass")).value.trim();
    });
```

Em jQuery:

```
$("#enter").on("click", function () {
        $("[required]", $(this).closest("form")).filter(function (i, e) {
            return !$(e).val().trim();
        }).val('');

        $("#numeroSerie").val($("#numeroSerie").val().trim());
        $("#user").val($("#user").val().trim());
        $("#pass").val($("#pass").val().trim());
    });
```

erro:

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   (document.getElementById(...).querySelectorAll(...) ,
>   this.closest(...)).filter is not a function
>       at HTMLButtonElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `.filter.call()` na lista de nós:

```
document.getElementById("enter").addEventListener("click", function () {
   [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("#form-login [required]"), function (e) {
      if(!e.value.trim()) e.value = '';
   });

   (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("numeroSerie")).value = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("numeroSerie")).value.trim();
   (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("user")).value = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("user")).value.trim();
   (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("pass")).value = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("pass")).value.trim();
});
```

O seletor `"#form-login [required]"` irá buscar dentro do `form#form-login` todos os elementos `required`.

Comment: muito bom cara, funcionou perfeitamente... eu só não entendi qual é a do array vazio antes do .filter.call()